# Nsis: Modifying a Json file using NsJson

Tags: json, nsis

I am trying to modify a file abc.json on desktop to change the value of dummy node to say, 500.

```
{

"home": {

  "abcd":   {

          "dummy":100
}

},
```

I am using nsJson plugin as following:
code:

```
var DESK

function JsonDemo

strcpy $DESK "C:\Users\zaidi.miraz\Desktop"

nsJSON::Set /file $DESK\abc.json

nsJSON::Set `homepage` `abcd` `dummy` /value `500`

functionend
```

But this is not working as the mentioned json file still holds the value of dummy=100.

What am I doing wrong?
Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually save your changes back to the file! Use `nsJSON::Serialize`...

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I can read the value, but not write it / save it.